# Que veut dire « traîner la gueuse » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, argot

Que veut dire « traîner la gueuse » dans cette phrase :

> Où tu vas comme ça? Traîner la gueuse ?

Est-ce que c'est dans le sens littéral « faire tirer les porcs »?

Comment: Quelle est la langue origine de « faire tirer les porcs »? Quel sens à cette expression pour vous ?

Comment: Ma langue natale est l'arabe, Généralement, j'utilise la magie de Google pour faire la translation des autres langues, mais dans certains cas comme ceci...... l'ordinateur reste toujours bête et discipliné et on fait appel au cerveau de l'être humain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Traîner » ici a le sens de « courir », TLF *II. A. b*.

L'expression habituelle est « courir la gueuse » une gueuse étant une femme qui vit de larcins ou de prostitution. Par extension le mot désigne une « débauchée,  femme qui s'adonne au plaisir sans retenue. » (*Dictionnaire du Français non conventionnel* - J. Cellard, A. Rey).
*Courir la gueuse*, *traîner la gueuse* c'est aller draguer, chercher à séduire. Voir le *[Bob dictionnaire argotique populaire familier](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=17402)*

Il est peu habituel d'employer traîner de façon transitive dans ce sens là. En général traîner dans le sens d'errer, s'emploie avec un complément de lieu. Mais l'expression se comprend tout à fait.

Je ne connais pas l'expression « faire tirer les porcs ». Mais porc renvoyant au sexe féminin je ne vois pas le rapport ici (surtout avec « faire tirer »).